# button element events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

HTML

```
<div id="pressed">I'm shown when button pressed</div>
<div id="relaxed">I'm shown when button relaxed</div>
<button>press_me</button>
```

CSS

```
#pressed {
 display: none;   
}​

JS

$('button').mousedown(function() {
    $('#pressed').show();
    $('#relaxed').hide();
});

$('button').bind('mouseup ',function() {
    $('#pressed').hide();
    $('#relaxed').show();
});
```

​
When I push and hold mouse button  down and move mouse out of the button element than relax button 
second handler do not fire, so `#pressed` div still active and `#relaxed` is not, I can setup `mouseout` event, but in that case button element will look as pushed. But event for relax already fired.

Which event handler should I set to acheive expected behaviour ? 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pn47K/3/)

Comment: ...but what *is* the expected behavior?

Comment: when i relax button message *I'm shown when button relaxed* appears

Comment: In what browser does the button look pressed when you move the mouse out, this is unexpected behavior of the browser and can be "pathced" with custom style maybe. In firefox adding mouseout is all you need.

Comment: @HMR google-chrome browser

Comment: so, it seems it also needed crossbrowser solution...

Comment: and in firefox it will get other unexpected - hold mouse down, out of the button and than back pointer over the button again, without relaxing, with mouseout you will see pushed button and *relaxed* message http://jsfiddle.net/epQMy/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with this JS:

```
var delm = document.documentElement ? document.documentElement : document.body;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vusan/pn47K/10/)

Answer (score 1):

My best bet is to use a global variable or a variable attached to that dom and attach the mousedown event on document instead of button.

```
var btn_mousedown = false;
$('button').mousedown(function() {
    $('#pressed').show();
    $('#relaxed').hide();
    btn_mousedown = true;
});

/* When I push mouse down and move out of button, than relax button
I do not get that event triggered, how to fix ? 
*/
$(document).bind('mouseup ', function() {
    if (btn_mousedown == true) {
        $('#pressed').hide();
        $('#relaxed').show();
        btn_mousedown = false;
    }
});​
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/atif089/pn47K/8/

Comment: I made almost same solution without additional var :)  http://jsfiddle.net/epQMy/ I'll accept the answer if no other way

Comment: post it here, ill upvote it :-) you can also select that as best answer

Comment: P.S - Your answer is awesome! Great Optimization

Comment: `if (btn_mousedown = true) {` - really?

Comment: @Ian heard of something called `typos`?

Comment: It doesn't really help or do anything when the text is fixed yet the fiddle is not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe is because of the button, it will always look like its pushed because the mouse button is still on hold, regardless if mouse pointer is on top of the button or not. Maybe this can be accomplished with a custom styled button.

JS:

```
$('#im-a-button').mousedown(function() {
   $('#pressed').show();
   $('#relaxed').hide();
});

$('#im-a-button').mouseup(function() {
   $('#pressed').hide();
   $('#relaxed').show();
});

$('#im-a-button').mouseout(function(){
   $('#pressed').hide();
   $('#relaxed').show();
});
```

​
MARKUP:

```
<div id="pressed">I'm shown when button pressed</div>
<div id="relaxed">I'm shown when button relaxed</div>
<p id="im-a-button">Press Me</p>
```

CSS:

```
#pressed {
 display: none;   
}

#im-a-button {
  color: blue;    
  cursor: pointer;   
}

#im-a-button:hover {
  color: red;       
}
```

Comment: it just mimic problem, not solves, also mouseout will be fired even if you not pushed mouse before...

Comment: Yes the event will fire, but visually there is no difference because even though the user didn't press the button, the style will still be the same as when the user actually press the button.

Comment: big difference, the events often used not only to update DOM.

Answer (score -1):

add `mouseleave`

```
$('button').bind('mouseup mouseleave',function() {
    $('#pressed').hide();
    $('#relaxed').show();
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pn47K/6/

Comment: then need to see what expected behavior is, not understanding issue otherwise

Comment: @charlietfl expected is that - when button rendered pushed, show `pushed` message, when it rendered relaxed show `relaxed` message, in question comments, here are found different behaviour for different browsers, last comment show also why in firefox mouseout will also not work as expected.